# One of two Android ListView filling too much space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I would like to obtain this layout for an Android app for mobile phones:

```
Icon - Object1
List with entries related to Object1

Icon - Object2
List with entries related to Object2
```

So far I have used the following layout tree (edited graphically with the editor in Android Studio):

> Root-LinearLayout
>
> > Vertical LinearLayout
> >
> > > Horizontal LinearLayout with icon and text
> > >
> > > ListView
> >
> > Vertical LinearLayout
> >
> > > Horizontal LinearLayout with icon and text
> > >
> > > ListView

May be this is not the best way to organize such layout (may be I should use lists with header, but suggestions very welcome), however it can be a good case for understanding deeper how ListView works.

This is the graphical layout generated:

[image: wrong layout]

the blue row corresponds to the first LinearLayout. As you can see from the second screenshot that follows, the second list goes all the way down to Hell, bringing me with her. Is there any way to make the lists respect the `wrap_content`+ `weight` behaviour?

[image: very long list]

The XML code follows. I have tried several combos (both reasonable and unreasonable) of layout:weights but none works. I also tried to set the `min-width` of the first LinearLayout (the hidden one), but nothing changes.

Could you please help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView15"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Object1"
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView16"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Object2"
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you put your `ListView`s inside of the child `LinearLayout`s which hold the `LinearLayout` that has the `TextView` and `ImageView`. You also should be using `"0dp"` for the `height` when using `weight` with a vertical layout.

Something like this, I believe, should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView15"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Object1"
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_weight=".8" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note the other changes: I gave the inner-`LinearLayout` an arbitrary `weight` of ".2" then the `ListView` a `weight` of ".8". And, of course, set the height to "0dp". You may need to play with those `weight`s a bit but I think doing something like that for both first child `LinearLayout`s should get you close.

That may get your current layout to work but using headers and/or an `ExpandableListView` may be a better option.

Comment: You are right. I thought the ListView was inside of the vertical linear layout (as I wrote in the question).

Comment: I think there is a bug in the Visual Editor. The list is shown as inside of the Vertical layout (as I wrote in my question), but it is actually outside of it, as clearly seen in the XML.

Comment: That's possible especially if you happen to be using Eclipse. Sometimes you need to close and reopen it, clean the project, or dance a jig to get it to act correctly.